# CSS: Positioning

Tags: css, position, css-position

So I have the following sequence of html:

```
<div class="box-content">
   <div class="box1 box"></div>
   <div class="box2 box"></div>
   <div class="box3 box"></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to display them like the following image:[image: positioning]

Does anybody know the appropriate css to do so?

Comment: Go learn the grid system of Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid. You'll be amazed how it's a life saver and it's also responsive for tablet and mobile devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `Flexbox`.

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box-content {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: #22B14C;
  margin: 10px;
}
.box2, .box3{
  flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 20px);
}

.box1 {
  flex: 0 0 calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box-content">
   <div class="box1 box">One</div>
   <div class="box2 box">Two</div>
   <div class="box3 box">Three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  color: white;
}
.box-content {
  width: 700px;
  height: 210px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  border:10px solid red;
}
.box1 {
  width: 680px;
  height: 80px;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
 }
.box2 {
  width: 325px;
  height: 80px;
  background: green;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
 }
.box3 {
  width: 325px;
  height: 80px;
  background: green;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box-content">
   <div class="box1 box">Box 1</div>
   <div class="box2 box">Box 2</div>
   <div class="box3 box">Box 3</div>
</div>
```